# A JNI error has occurred in Serverless DynamoDB Local on Mac

Tags: serverless-framework

When I try to use DyanmoDB Local (https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dynamodb-local)

A JNI error has occurred.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
```

In terminal, java, javac version is samed.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_281
```

And $JAVA_HOME is not set. but it is not problem.

Because it was executed in other Mac without $JAVA_HOME